# could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 this error comes in pom.xml file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

when i created a new project in eclipse using maven i got this error at the first line in my pom.xml file
this is the code inside pom.xml and i got the error at first line.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoProject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DemoProject Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>DemoProject</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Probably some network issue, like proxy or firewall.

Comment: yes, you are right i have found that it is related with settings.xml fie in .m2 folder. Can you please tell me the about settings.xml file

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. What do you want to know about the `settings.xml`?

Comment: How is it related to the `settings.xml` file cause you wrote that you seemed to know very few about the `settings.xml` ...so how could you be sure?

Comment: i have tried to find the solution of this problem so that i found about settings.xml file and this file needs to be place under .m2 folder